# Identify bar colors of existing fig, ax

Tags: unit-testing, matplotlib

I have an existing fig, ax that are output from a function I cannot change.

```
fig, ax = locked_function(data)
```

I am creating a unit test and need to be able to look at `ax.bar`.

```
# The function I am looking for would let me check the color of a particular bar

assert ax.get_color_of_bar2() == 'red'
```

I can see the rectangle objects inside of `ax.get_children()` but they don't seem to have color attached to them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bar is essentially a [Rectangle](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) object. From it you can obtain the color by using the method `get_facecolor()`. Check the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot():
    N = 5
    Means = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
    Std = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
    ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
    width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    rects1 = ax.bar(ind, Means, width, color='r')
    return rects1

r = plot()
for i in r:
    print(i.get_facecolor())
plt.show()
```

, this returns both the tuples from the color of each bar (using print) and the plot itself:

```
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

[image: Bar plot with red bars in matplotlib]

You did not request it but perhaps it will help you in the future. When I'm stuck and do no know the correct method to obtain something (or change something) is usually do:

```
r = plot()
help(r[0])
```

This will return you the map of the object. Is not always easy to read but the functions will be printed like this:

```
 ...
 |  get_ec = get_edgecolor(self)
 |      Return the edge color of the :class:`Patch`.
 |  
 |  get_edgecolor(self)
 |      Return the edge color of the :class:`Patch`.
 |  
 |  get_extents(self)
 |      Return a :class:`~matplotlib.transforms.Bbox` object defining
 |      the axis-aligned extents of the :class:`Patch`.
 |  
 |  get_facecolor(self)
 |      Return the face color of the :class:`Patch`.
 |  
 |  get_fc = get_facecolor(self)
 |      Return the face color of the :class:`Patch`.
 |  
 |  get_fill(self)
 |      return whether fill is set
 ...
```

Another option is the `__dict__` property:

```
print(r[0].__dict__)
```

Which results in something like this:

```
{'_joinstyle': 'miter', '_gid': None, 'figure': <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x00000000025AF828>, '_angle': 0.0, '_original_edgecolor': 'k', '_hatch': None, '_transform': CompositeGenericTransform(TransformWrapper(BlendedAffine2D(IdentityTransform(),IdentityTransform())), CompositeGenericTransform(BboxTransformFrom(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.0, 0.0], [4.5, 35.0]]), TransformWrapper(BlendedAffine2D(IdentityTransform(),IdentityTransform())))), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.125, 0.09999999999999998], [0.9, 0.9]]), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.0, 0.0], [8.0, 6.0]]), Affine2D(array([[ 80.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  80.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.]])))))))), '_antialiased': True, '_remove_method': <function _AxesBase.add_patch.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000000004D068C8>, '_y': 0.0, '_facecolor': (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), '_snap': None, '_label': '_nolegend_', '_original_facecolor': array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]), '_rasterized': None, '_linestyle': 'solid', '_width': 0.35, '_combined_transform': IdentityTransform(), '_x': 0.0, '_oid': 0, '_sketch': None, '_alpha': None, 'eventson': False, '_transformSet': True, '_path_effects': [], 'clipbox': TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]), CompositeGenericTransform(CompositeGenericTransform(BboxTransformTo(Bbox([[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]])), Affine2D(array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]]))), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.125, 0.09999999999999998], [0.9, 0.9]]), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.0, 0.0], [8.0, 6.0]]), Affine2D(array([[ 80.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  80.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.]])))))))), '_picker': None, '_clippath': None, '_propobservers': {}, '_clipon': True, 'stale_callback': <function _stale_axes_callback at 0x000000000438C9D8>, '_animated': False, '_agg_filter': None, '_mouseover': False, '_stale': True, '_rect_transform': CompositeGenericTransform(BboxTransformTo(Bbox([[0.0, 0.0], [0.35, 20.0]])), Affine2D(array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]]))), '_axes': <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000000004BB4518>, '_url': None, '_linewidth': 1.0, '_height': 20.0, '_capstyle': 'butt', '_contains': None, '_fill': True, '_visible': True, '_edgecolor': (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: This is related but admittedly not what I asked but I input a hex color.  I am assuming those are RGB values it is spitting out.  Why are there 4 instead of 3?

Comment: @Chris Matplotlib works with floating point RGBA (0 to 1). The fourth element is the alpha channel for transparency. To obtain the RGBA from whatever hex or built-in color matplotlib has you might want to use [colors](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) library.